# Integer overflow in enums, loop through only named integers

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

How can I achieve this behavior?

```cpp
enum week {
    sunday=0, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday
};
```

```cpp
enum week day = saturday; // 6
// ++day => 0
```

```cpp
enum week day = sunday; // 0
// --day => 6
```

Comment: You'll have to wrap it up in functions that know the boundary values of the enum.

Comment: Use an `enum class` and define for yourself how the operator should behave.

Comment: Can I somehow overload `++` & `--` operator?

Comment: @JohnDoe That's exactly what NathanOliver is suggesting. For the signatures refer to the "outside class definition" column in the table here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec

Comment: What behavior are you expecting when you increment past the last enum?

Comment: You may want to use `day = (day + 1) % 7;`  or `day = (day + 6) % 7;`

Answer (score 3):

You could use a enum class and overload the operators for it (as suggested by @NathanOliver). The formulas suggested by @Thomas Matthews can be used to avoid having to deal with negative numbers:

**Enum + operator implementation**

`week` was renamed to `day` to avoid confusion (one enum value does not represent a whole week, only a single day)

```
enum class day : unsigned char {
    sunday = 0, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday
};

// preincrement
day& operator++(day& d)
{
    d = static_cast<day>((static_cast<unsigned char>(d) + 1) % 7);
    return d;
}

// postincrement
day operator++(day& d, int)
{
    day res = d;
    d = static_cast<day>((static_cast<unsigned char>(d) + 1) % 7);
    return res;
}

// predecrement
day& operator--(day& d)
{
    d = static_cast<day>((static_cast<unsigned char>(d) + 6) % 7);
    return d;
}

// postdecrement
day operator--(day& d, int)
{
    day res = d;
    d = static_cast<day>((static_cast<unsigned char>(d) + 6) % 7);
    return res;
}
```

**Test code**

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, day d)
{
    switch (d)
    {
    case day::monday:
        s << "Monday";
        break;
    case day::tuesday:
        s << "Tuesday";
        break;
    case day::wednesday:
        s << "Wednesday";
        break;
    case day::thursday:
        s << "Thursday";
        break;
    case day::friday:
        s << "Friday";
        break;
    case day::saturday:
        s << "Saturday";
        break;
    case day::sunday:
        s << "Sunday";
        break;
    }
    return s; 
}

int main() {
    day d1 = day::sunday;
    --d1;

    day d2 = day::saturday;
    ++d2;

    day d3 = day::wednesday;
    --d3;

    day d4 = day::wednesday;
    ++d4;

    std::cout << d1 << '\n'
        << d2 << '\n'
        << d3 << '\n'
        << d4 << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Saturday
Sunday
Tuesday
Thursday
```